# Linker error when building Login Demo

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm getting this error when I try to build the iOS Login Demo from https://github.com/firebase/login-demo-ios:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Firebase", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have updated the project Podfile to use Firebase 2.4.1 and updated the target to iOS 8.4 and am using XCode 7.0.1. How do I fix this?

Comment: You might want to create this as an issue on the Github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an issue on Github per @Frank van Puffelen's recommendation, and got this response (https://github.com/firebase/login-demo-ios/issues/15):

> This is due to a broken release for Firebase on CocoaPods. We're working on a fix for that. As a workaround until we release that you can point to 2.3.3 in the Podfile.

I imagine this would break any project pulling Firebase 2.4 from CocoaPods.